# C++, Use [] notation on pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, operator-keyword

I just noticed I can use [] on a pointer and it works, but I was wondering, if this is good to use it.

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4};
int *p=&a[1];
std::cout << p[0]; // returns 2;
std::cout << p[-1]; // returns 1;
std::cout << p[1]; // returns 3;
```

I always learned, you have to use it like this:

```
std::cout << *(p-1); 
std::cout << *(p+1);
```

But is it okay to use the operator []  on a pointer ?

Comment: Yes it's fine to use that, extremely common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C/C++, given a pointer `p` and integral value `k`, `p[k]` is evaluated as `*(p+k)`. Either form is fine to use as long as `p+k` points to valid memory.

If you have access to the C99 Standard, see section **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting, Paragraph 2**. It says:

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th element of `E1` (counting from zero).

If you have access to the C++11 standard, see section **5.2.1 Subscripting, Paragraph 1**. It says:

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type “pointer to `T`” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type.
>   The result is an lvalue of type “`T`.” The type “`T`” shall be a completely-defined object type. The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`

Comment: Okay thank you, didn't find info right away, will select this answer as correct after waiting period ;)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to great answer by R Sahu you can also do

```
std::cout << p[-1]; // returns 1;
std::cout << p[1]; // returns 3;

std::cout << 1[p]; // returns 3;
std::cout << (-1)[p]; // returns 1;
```

See : [Ideone](http://ideone.com/MeW3S7)

For pointer `p` and integer value `k` :

`p[k]` and `k[p]` both are evaluating to `*(p+k)`. So, both are same.

But following one is not same

```
std::cout << -1[p]; // returns -3;
std::cout << (-1)[p]; // returns 1;
```